# Overlay rectangle on Fabric.js image

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a custom image class as follows. What i want to do is after applying a certain logic, I want to show a colored border on the bounding box of the image. Since setting the borders makes the image selectable i was wondering if there was a way to somehow overlay a rectangle and make it transparent and just toggle its border color. How could that be done with a custom image class.

If there is a better way to accomplish this, please let us know

```
fabric.CustomImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {
    type: 'named-image',
    initialize: function (element, options) {
        this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
        options && this.set('name', options.name);
        options && this.set('rot', options.rot);
        options && this.set('rawURL', options.rawURL);
        options && this.set('belongsto', options.belongsto);
    },
    toObject: function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'),
                                         { name: this.name, rot: this.rot });
    }
});
```

based on the suggestions tried the following

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

//// create Custom Image class from Image class

```
fabric.CustomImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {
    type: 'named-image',
    initialize: function (element, options) {
        this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
        options && this.set('name', options.name);
        options && this.set('rot', options.rot);
        options && this.set('rawURL', options.rawURL);
        options && this.set('belongsto', options.belongsto);
        options && this.set('myrect', true);
    },
    toObject: function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'),
                                         {
                                             name: this.name,
                                             rot: this.rot,
                                             myrect : ''
                                         });
    },
    _render: function (ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
        var r = new fabric.Rect();
        r.left = this.left;
        r.top = this.top;
        r.height = this.height;
        r.width = this.width;
        r.borderColor = 'red';
        r.strokeWidth = 2;
        ctx.myrect = (r);
      //  ctx.add(r);
    }
});
```

still not working, any ideas?

ok, so i am trying the following code but still cannot see a border around the image

```
    var currentObj = ChrImages.d[j];

    //closure, create a scope for specific variables
    (function (obj) {
        fabric.util.loadImage(obj.URL, function (img) {
            var customImage = new fabric.CustomImage(img, {
                name: obj.Name,
                rot: obj.Rotation,
                rawURL: obj.RawURL,
                belongsto: obj.BelongsTo,
                left: obj.PosX,
                top: obj.PosY,
                angle: obj.Rotation,
                perPixelTargetFind: true,

            });

            customImage.stroke = true;
            customImage.strokeWidth = 2;
            customImage.lockScalingX = true;
            customImage.lockScalingY = true;
            customImage.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveWhite());
            canvas.add(customImage);
            groupWorkingImages.add(customImage);
        });

    })(currentObj);
```

any thoughts?

Comment: You could try just grouping image and rectangle together, via `fabric.Group`.

Comment: yes, i would have generally done that except that i have many many images, so managing all of those would not be easy. just wished there was some other way to make that rectangle a part of the custom class and just its properties

Comment: You can do custom class as well. Just render both image and rectangle in _render method. See http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#subclassing

Comment: ok, that will work. in that case how could i possibly change the properties of that rectangle such as opaque transparent color etc?

Comment: Store a reference to rectangle from within your class

Comment: I tried the following but cannot get it to work, any ideas?

Comment: new code in the edit, but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Why aren't you just using stroke on image?

Comment: see the new code but i still cant get it to work.